# How can I match this array-like notation using regex in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I'm trying to match the following array-like pattern with regex:

`foo[bar][baz][bim]`

**I almost have it with the following regex:**

`~([^[]+)(?:\[(.+?)\])*~gm`

However, the capturing groups only include:

```
Full match: foo[bar][baz][bim]
Group 1: foo
Group 2: bim
```

I can't figure out why it's only capturing the last occurrence of the `[]` structure. I'd like it capture foo, bar, baz, and bim in this case.

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repeated capturing groups in PCRE don't remember the values of each previous pattern. For this you need to invoke `\G` token:

```
(?|(\w+)|\G(?!\A)\[([^][]*)\])
```

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/zkHCp2/1)

Regex breakdown:

- `(?|` Start of a branch reset group

  - `(\w+)` Capture word characters
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!\A)` Conitnue from where previous match ends
  - `\[` Match an opening bracket
  - `([^][]*)` Capture any thing except `[` and `]`
  - `\]` Match a closing bracket
- `)` End of cluster

PHP code:

```
preg_match_all('~(?|(\w+)|\G(?!\A)\[([^][]*)\])~', 'foo[bar][baz][bim]', $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

This can also be parsed without regex.
Remove the closing `]` and then explode on the opening `[`.

```
$str = "foo[bar][baz][bim]";

$str = str_replace("]","",$str);
$arr = explode("[", $str);
var_dump($arr);
```

Returns:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "foo"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "bar"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "baz"
  [3]=>
  string(3) "bim"
}
```

Where the first item is the "array" name and the following is the children/path.

Comment: Good point. Can't accept because my question is about regex but I'm going to try this too, thanks.

Comment: @TimothyFisher I honestly feel that Revo is worthy of the accepted since he nailed the regex, but it is your choice what answer you accept. It has nothing to do with what you initially asked. Think of it as if someone asked how to store plain text usernames and passwords in a text file. Obviously the answer how to read/write text files is the answer but not really.